# Can I develop a trigger to put on two tables?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to develop triggers that will be placed on both the customer and child tables that will track any record deleted and place them in the Audit_Log Table.

This is audit log table

```
create table Audit_Log
(
audit_Id              int         primary key,
Name            varchar(20)         ,
Date_of_Birth   date                ,
Gender          char(1)             ,
Parish          varchar(20)         ,
Mobile          integer             ,
Mobile_Provider varchar(7)          ,
age             integer, 
age_cat         varchar(20),
audit_action    varchar(30),
audit_table     varchar(25),
audit_date      date    default GetDate()
)
go
```

This is the child_list table

```
   create table child_list
 (
 child_list_Id              int         primary key,
 Name            varchar(20)         ,
 Date_of_Birth   date                ,
 Gender          char(1)             ,
 Parish          varchar(20)         ,
 Mobile          integer             ,
 Mobile_Provider varchar(7)          ,
 age             integer, 
 age_cat            varchar(20)
  )
 go
```

Customer table has fields (Offer_date, Customer_id, Offer_value, Product_name, Acceptance_status, Employee_ID)

Comment: A trigger is always **table-specific** - I highly doubt you'll be able to create a trigger that can work with both tables (unless those tables have all the same columns etc.)

Comment: Create one procedure and use it in triggers.